# Add to Hashtable (java) without using .put method

Tags: java, hashtable

I wish to create the add method of Hashtable without implementing the Java api class or methods. This means that I have to add a value to a key in the Hashtable without using mytable.put(key,value). Could anyone kindly give me any idea how this can be done. Thanks alot.

Comment: Sure: use the `putAll` method.  Other than that, there isn't any way.

Comment: the putAll method is part of the java api methods. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use to take advantage of those..

Comment: could mytable(key)=value; work ?

Comment: nope. You can't do mytable(key)=value .

Comment: It sounds like you're supposed to rewrite a hash table from scratch, not to reuse the Java `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 1):

This adds a value to a key without using mytable.put(key,value)

```
    Hashtable<Object, Object> myTable = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    for (Entry e : myTable.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getKey().equals(myKey) {
            e.setValue(myValue);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Just an add on to this: How would this change if the hashtable had 1 key and 2 Values instead of one value. I see that < Object,Object,Object> does not work, since the hashtable can only take 2 arguments..

Comment: Adding to above , the Value parameter is Object, so use that to store 2 values in it , And use a bean to get the output , or you may use any collections even to store if you wont have any other choice

Answer (score 0):

Use putAll() method..

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...; // wherever you get it from //Using Map or Hashtable 

Map<String, Object> toBeAdded = new HashMap<String, Object>();  

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {  
    // Determine if you need to add anything, add it to 'toBeAdded'  
}  

// Finally, add the new elements to the original map  
map.putAll(toBeAdded);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty straightforward and a new way of approaching this problem. Unfortunately my project doesn't allow me to use any Java predefined methods such as put. or putAll. But thanks for your suggestion.